# tkinter - How to adjust text position relative to checkbox image?

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

Is it possible to move the checkbox description closer to the checkbox?

[image: CheckBox]

```py
character_set = LabelFrame(text=" Example ")

checkbtn0 = PhotoImage(file="example_off.png")
checkbtn1 = PhotoImage(file="example_on.png")

checktestbox = IntVar()

checktest = Label(character_set, image=checkbtn0)
checktest.bind("<Button-1>", Custom)
checktest.grid(padx=8, pady=4, row=0, column=0)

checktext = Label(character_set, text="Upper case (A-Z)")
checktext.grid(row=0, column=1)

character_set.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=4, pady=4)
```

Comment: "It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details" Completely not possible to add

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
checktest.grid(padx=8, pady=4, row=0, column=0)
```

this will add `8 pixels` to the left and right of your `Label`.

To reduce or even set to `0` use this instead:

```
checktest.grid(padx=(8,0), pady=4, row=0, column=0)
```

This allows different values to padding left and right.

> `padx(a,b)`

- a is the padding-left
- b is the padding-right

I'm gonna to say `padx` is simliar to padding-left and padding-right in HTML.
If you remove `padx` at all, the padding-left and padding-right will be `zero`.

Comment: @stovfl ```padx(a,b)```.a is the padding-left.b is the padding-right,is it?**has no distance to the left**,I mean is that the padding-left is zero. I apologize for my poor English expression.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: adjust text position besides checkbox

**Relevant**:

- [customize-horizontal-padding-between-image-and-text-in-label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333359/python-tkinter-customize-horizontal-padding-between-image-and-text-in-label-wid)

---

**Reference**:

- [The Tkinter Label Widget - `compound=`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method)

  > **`compound=`**
  >   Controls how to combine text and image in the label. If this option is set to one of BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT, or TOP, the image is drawn besides the text.
- [The Tkinter Place Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm)

  > **`place(**options)`**
  >   Used in specialized cases, most importantly, by compound widgets to position.
- [The Tkinter Checkbutton Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm#Tkinter.Checkbutton.config-method)

  > **`Checkbutton(parent, text=<str>, variable=<tk.VariableClasses>)`**
  >   The checkbutton widget is used to choose between two distinct values (usually switching something on or off).

---

1. Compound your own `Checkbutton` widget, using `Frame`, `Label`

   ```
   class Checkbutton(tk.Frame):
       off_image = PhotoImage(...
       on_image = PhotoImage(...

       def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
           text = kwargs.pop('text', None)
           self.callback = kwargs.pop('callback', None)
           super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

           self.chkbox = tk.Label(parent, image=Checkbutton.off_image)
           self.chkbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
           self.chkbox.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_click)

           self.label = tk.Label(parent, text=text)
           self.chkbox.grid(row=0, column=1)

       def on_click(self, event):
           # Implements exchanging image
           pass

   chkbtn = Checkbutton(root, text="Upper case (A-Z)", callback=Custom)
   chkbtn.grid(padx=8, pady=4, row=0, column=0)
   ```
2. Using `Label(..., compound='left')`

   ```
   checktext = Label(root, image=checkbtn0, text="Upper case (A-Z)", compound='left')
   ```
3. Using `.place(x, y)`

   ```
   checktest = Label(root, image=checkbtn0)
   checktest.place(x=..., y=...)

   checktext = Label(root, text="Upper case (A-Z)")
   checktext.place(x=..., y=...)
   ```
4. Inherit from `class tk.Checkbutton`, use your own images
   See this answer: [checkbutton different image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58560611/7414759)

   ```
   class Checkbutton(tk.Checkbutton):
       off_image = PhotoImage(...
       on_image = PhotoImage(...

       def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
           self.var = tk.IntVar()
           super().__init__(parent, 
                            image=Checkbutton.off_image, 
                            selectimage=Checkbutton.on_image, 
                            indicatoron=False,
                            onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=self.var,
                            **kwargs)
   ```